# Is $A$ compact, $f(A)$ uniformly continuous and is $f^{-1}$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

$X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $A\subseteq X$, $A$ is bounded. map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous.

Questions:

1. Is $A$ necessarily compact?
2. Is $f(A)$ uniformly continuous?
3. If given that $f$ is a bijection and $f(A)$ is compact, is $f^{-1}$ necessarily continuous?

Tried: If $A$ is closed and bounded, then $A$ must be compact hence compactness of $f(A)$ follows. So the question reduces to "is boundedness of $A$ sufficient for compactness?" Also, I think 3 is correct because bijection and compact domain and codomain should be enough for homeomorphism...

I am new to topology so really appreciate any help!

Comment: To $1:$ Where is said that $A$ is closed? To $2:$ Do you mean $f_{|A}?$

Comment: @mfl $A$ is not given as closed. I'm saying that if it is closed then it must be compact, since $A$ is bounded. And what is $f_{|A}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1,2 no. Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1]$

For 3, no. Consider identity map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ , where the first one with discrete metric and the second one with standard metric.

Comment: nice counterexamples!